# How to mark logical sections of code in Java comments?

Tags: java, comments

Java classes are generally divided into logical "blocks". Is there a convention to mark these sections? Ideally, it would be supported by the major IDEs.

I personally use this method:

```
//// Section name here ////
```

However, some editors seem to have problems with this.

As an example, in Objective-C code you can use this method:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Section name here
```

This will result in a menu in XCode that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: as an iOS developer, this is what I missed the most when I started with Android Studio

Comment: downvoted:  With modern IDEs and languages it's a poor practice.  If you have to sectionize your code, you're probably already breaking the Single Responsibility Principle and it's better to split out to different classes/files.  

If there are multiple editors it will likely be out-of-synch after a while anyway, as some will follow this, some will refactor and re-organize the code, or automatic save and format actions will break it.

Comment: downvoted: I agree with @f.carlsen. If you structure your class with comments, you are very likely to break [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: To haters: call me when Java supports Swift-style class extensions where you can logically separate your interface implementations into different sections. And yes, a class can do well to implement multiple interfaces at the same time.

Comment: Upvoted. It is good practice to organise your class even when it is already has a single responsibility. I like to keep the implementation of each interface in a separate section, for example.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I personally use 80-chars line separators, like this :

```
public class Client {

    //================================================================================
    // Properties
    //================================================================================

    private String name;
    private boolean checked;

    //================================================================================
    // Constructors
    //================================================================================

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(String name, boolean checked) {
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    //================================================================================
    // Accessors
    //================================================================================

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

}
```

Of course, this may seem a bit overkill for such a small POJO, but believe me, it proved very useful in some huge projects where I had to browse through big source files and quickly find the methods I was interested in. It also helps understand the source code structure.

In Eclipse, I have created a set of custom templates (Java -> Editor -> Templates in Eclipse's Preferences dialog) that generate those bars, eg.
 - sepa (SEParator for Accessors)
 - sepp (SEParator for Properties)
 - sepc (SEParator for Constructors)
 - etc.

I also modified the standard "new class" template (Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates in Eclipse Preferences screen)

Also, there is an old Eclipse plugin called [Coffee-bytes](http://themindstorms.blogspot.com/2006/11/my-eclipse-code-folding-plugin.html), which enhanced the way Eclipse folds portions of code.
I don't know if it still works, but I remembed one could define arbitrary foldable zones by adding special comments, like // [SECTION] or something.
It might still work in recent Eclipse revisions, so take a look.

Answer (score 189):

For intellij/android studio there is an amazing solution.
Start with:
`//region Description`
and end with:
`//endregion`

The shortcut for that is in the menu you can open with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (Windows)

You can also add your own line for additional visual separation if you need it. 
The region can be contracted and expanded at will with the +/- buttons like any function.
You can also navigate between regions with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd>)

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/folding-custom-regions-with-line-comments.html).

Example:

```
//region Parceler Implementation
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(this.die, 0);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.dieSprite, 0);
}

private DieVm(Parcel in) {
    this.die = in.readParcelable(Die.class.getClassLoader());
    this.dieSprite = in.readParcelable(Sprite.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<DieVm> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DieVm>() {
    public DieVm createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new DieVm(source);
    }

    public DieVm[] newArray(int size) {
        return new DieVm[size];
    }
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//endregion
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful Thank you Andrey. BTW I'm using eclipse keyboard shortcut layout and I don't think the shortcuts works for mebut the '// region' works great

Comment: I don't see any way for this to show up in the structure view, so I'm still using fake empty members (along with suppress unused warning).

Comment: is there any way to show those region in Android Studio (Structure view)?

Comment: Link is dead; this [IntelliJ IDEA blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/) may be a helpful reference. It also mentions [NetBeans-like style folding items](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds) `<editor-fold ...>`.

Comment: the best answer

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC Current Android Studio (2021.1.1) does show the regions in the Structure view.

Comment: I don't know why but my intellij only shows //region but without the following long line of dashes

Answer (score 14):

Eclipse defines an [@category javadoc annotation](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.2-200606291905/new_noteworthy/eclipse-news-part2.html) (scroll to section marked "Category support") which enables filtering by category in the outline view. Not exactly what you want. I'm suprised nobody has written an Eclipse plugin which offers a view like your screen shot.

Comment: In most java views, however, it is possible to filter class members according to their categories, in order to hide as default getters and setters, as an example.

Comment: no idea why I can't use @category in Android Studio, do you know what can I do to achieve same behavior on it?

Answer (score 6):

I liked that also when i was using xcode. For eclipse i use ctrl+o (quick outline) to navigate through a Java class.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html); or use the following as a simple "separator" (single or 3 lines):

```
/** RecyclerOnItemClickListener */

/** 
 * RecyclerOnItemClickListener
 */
```

So that in IDE it appears in a different color other than the unobtrusive commented grey.

Answer (score 4):

Using unnecessary comments/markers in the code to help working may not be a good practice. I have little idea about xcode and java development but all major IDE's support finding the members with out any special markers like eclipse shows the methods and members using outline view which can be triggered using `ctrl+O`, Intellij (which I prefer using more on mac and had a community edition too) has the same outline concept and can be quickly accessed using (ctrl + f12). So my point here is don't use any unnecessary mark up in the code as all (or atleast good/sane) IDE's can do it automatically.

Comment: Agree, section markers only add to visual clutter. Your class ought to be tightly focused enough to make these things irrelevent.

Comment: Sure, but having methods grouped into logical and marked-off sections can help to impose visual order on what would otherwise be a flat list of methods. Sometimes you don't know exactly which method you want, and it's nice to take in the related methods all at once, and have some idea that you're seeing the full extent of the related code.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no such thing as a supported specification for grouping class members together. You can use what-ever comment convention you like, but chances are it will not be supported by any tool.

It is better to group related members into separate class via inheritance or aggregation. This is considered a good OOP style

Comment: Splitting out sections of code seems only possible in theory. For example, take a class Client with attributes such as name, and a collection "invoices". I would love to be able to split this into a section "name" that contains getters/setters for name and a section "invoices" that contains add/remove methods for invoices.


It seems impractical to split these up into a class hierarchy that can only add one attribute per class, i.e. "NamedEntity", "NameAndAddressEntity", "Invoicable", ...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Andrey's answer provided, to use //region //endregion, we insert [BigAscii letters][1] in major code sections. When scrolling fast, it really stands out. One drawback of this approach is that I cannot search for it so you'd need to add a search term just below the "banner" like I do below.

> Blockquote

```
//    _      _____          _____                  _   _
//   | |    |  __ \   /\   |  __ \      /\        | | | |
//   | |    | |  | | /  \  | |__) |    /  \  _   _| |_| |__
//   | |    | |  | |/ /\ \ |  ___/    / /\ \| | | | __| '_ \
//   | |____| |__| / ____ \| |       / ____ \ |_| | |_| | | |
//   |______|_____/_/    \_\_|      /_/    \_\__,_|\__|_| |_|
//
//   Search here with: LDAP Auth
```

[1]: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&c=c%2B%2B&f=Big&t=LDAP Auth

Answer (score 1):

A modern IDE allows you to view your code in many different ways, and even reorganize it.    Eclipse even allows you to view the definition of the code you have the cursor on in another panel.

Any automatic reorganizing of your code, will cause such markup to break down.

If you want grouping then consider putting things belonging together in the same class, and things not belonging together in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can cluster your methods, do another class specifically for that concept that you want to capture in a section. Go ahead, creating files is free.

Answer (score -21):

For IntelliJ i do like:

```
        public void ________________INIT__________________() {};
```

looking pretty in file structure!

Comment: This seems like a very bad solution.  Why declare additional methods when your goal is code organization?

Comment: That's to make the whole file segmented in the Structure view.

Comment: this is only one which looking really in android studio, propose u own as answer and i will use

Comment: @user170317 http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/

Comment: Worst thing I have ever seen !! and it's PUBLIC !  o_O

Comment: This is the only answer which shows up in the structure view, and works across different IDE's.  Make it private and grin and bear it, or don't use it if you don't like it, but don't hide this answer from other readers by down-voting it into oblivion.

Comment: I think this is the worst recommendation i've even seen :( RIP java

Comment: I came to IntelliJ from Xcode and I use this (before I saw it here) to get a delineated structure that is similar to Xcode. I am surprised at the down votes it has got... I don't see the terrible problem, in fact I find it a useful work-around for an IDE shortcoming in terms of usability (code can be lengthy but organised, right?). I found regions to be less than helpful, and they have other issues, as discussed here: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/

Comment: JESUS CHRIST - y u do dis