# Specific comment blocks in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I often see comment blocks like:

```
// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================
```

Is there any way to add them in Eclipse fast?

Comment: `ctrl shift /` will add a block comment, but not in the format you have posted.

Comment: BTW: when you need to separate fields and methods like this, your classes probably are too long. As a rule of thumb, a class should fit into 1-2 screens.

Comment: Please read the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379197/how-to-mark-logical-sections-of-code-in-java-comments to see why this approach is wrong in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating a code template: -> `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Templates`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own comment template in Eclipse.
I think you can do this under: `Main Menu -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Configure generated code and comments`.

Take a look at these instructions [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-add-your-own-comment-template-in-eclipse.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604456/395659) i think it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-/ to toggle "//" comments and Ctrl-Shift-/ to toggle "/* */" comments. At least for Java, anyway - other tooling may have different shortcuts.

Ctrl-\ will remove a block of either comment, but won't add comments.